# Smart pointer (unique_ptr) instead of raw pointer as class member

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, memory-leaks, unique-ptr

Given a class hierarchy:

```
class A {

private:
  string * p_str;

public:
  A() : p_str(new string())
  {
  }

  virtual ~A() {
    delete p_str;
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  B() {
  }

  virtual ~B() override {
  }

  virtual void Test() {
    cout << "B::Test()" << endl;
  }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  B b;

  b.Test();

    return 0;
}
```

There is a `p_str` pointer to string (no matter what object it points to).

Is there any advantage of replacing it to `std::unique_ptr` except for not writing `delete p_str`?

```
class A {

private:
  std::unique_ptr<string> p_str;

public:
  A() : p_str(make_unique<string>())
  virtual ~A() {}

}
```

? If constructor of any derived class throws an exception, there memory leak will be occured in any variant of code.

**UPD** I tried this code:

## include

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Pointed {
public:
  Pointed() { std::cout << "Pointed()\n"; }
  ~Pointed() { std::cout << "~Pointed()\n"; }
};

class A1 {
private:
  Pointed * p_str;

public:
  A1() : p_str(new Pointed()) {
    cout << "A1()\n";
    throw "A1 constructor";
  }

  virtual ~A1() {
    cout << "~A1()\n";
    delete p_str;
  }
};

class B1 : public A1 {
public:
  B1() {
    throw "B constructor";
  }

  virtual ~B1() override {
    cout << "~B1()\n";
  }

  virtual void Test() {
    cout << "B1::Test()" << endl;
  }
};

class A2 {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<Pointed> p_str;

public:
  A2() : p_str(make_unique<Pointed>()) {
    cout << "A2()\n";
    throw "A2 constructor";
  }
  
  virtual ~A2() {
    cout << "~A2()\n";
  }
};


class B2 : public A2 {
public:
  B2() {
    cout << "B2()\n";
    throw "B2 constructor";
  }

  virtual ~B2() override {
    cout << "~B2()\n";
  }

  virtual void Test() {
    cout << "B2::Test()" << endl;
  }
};

int main(int, char**) {
  cout << "B1::A1 (raw pointers)\n";

  try {
    B1 b1;
  }
  catch (...) {
    cout << "Exception thrown for B1\n";
  }

  cout << "\nB2::A2 (unique pointers)\n";

  try {
    B2 b2;
  }
  catch (...) {
    cout << "Exception thrown for b2\n";
  }

  cin.get();

  return 0;
}
```

And output is:

```
B1::A1 (raw pointers)
Pointed()
A1()
Exception thrown for B1

B2::A2 (unique pointers)
Pointed()
A2()
~Pointed()
Exception thrown for b2
```

So, consequence is that `unique_ptr` is deleted automatically when exception occurs in constructor of the same class where member was declared.

Comment: "If constructor of any derived class throws an exception, there memory leak will be occured in any variant of code."

Are you *sure?* It looks to me like there [won't be a leak regardless](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0aabaeaa456c99ec). Since it's a child object throwing the exception in the constructor, the destructor of the base object will be called when the exception is thrown.

Comment: @jaggedSpire sorry for "of any derived", but if exception occured in constructor of class, where member is defined, there will be memory leak: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3bd94aa1c8fbb7df

Comment: That is correct, though not what you originally asserted. Just remember to be careful with your wording--when it comes to exceptions, *where* you throw makes all the difference sometimes. Since you fixed your statement so it doesn't say there will be a memory leak if the inheritor class throws an exception, I'd be willing to delete my original comment.

Comment: @jaggedSpire please, don't! Let all discussion stay here for future readers'  understanding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With raw pointer you can have double delete, since you have no manually realized copy c-tor and assignment operator.

```
A a;
A b = a; // b.p_str store the same address, that a.p_str
```

With `unique_ptr` you can't copy/assign object, but you can move it, without writing move c-tor/move assignment operator.

```
A a;
A b = a; // cannot do this, since `unique_ptr` has no copy constructor.
A b = std::move(a); // all is okay, now `b` stores `unique_ptr` with data and `a` stores `nullptr`
```

But actually, I have no idea, why you should store pointer here, instead of just object of type `std::string`, it's the best solution in your example.

Comment: `string` was just for example

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ForEveR's reply, using a `unique_ptr` tells the reader that there's *only one object* referring to (and in this case, owning) that string.  With a bare pointer, whoever's reading your code has no idea how many other objects, locals, or whatever else (singletons?  Globals?) access and/or modify that string.